# Is a body of gas cooler in its upper portion as a result of gravity?

Tags: thermodynamics, atmospheric-science

I read an article a couple of hours ago named [Hydrostatic Lapse](https://medium.com/criminal-clouds/hydrostatic-lapse-part-1-of-3-e8a1534cd12d) which makes the case for a phenomenon that I thought was well and truly confirmed; that gravity is responsible for the cooling of gas with altitude. However I discover in the sequel article that this phenomenon is supposedly in conflict with the second law of thermodynamics.

After a bit of research, I find that Vanquish Opprobrium (author of those articles) isn't the only one who thinks the two are incompatible. Robert G brown from Duke University also makes the case for incompatibility in [Refutation of Stable Thermal Equilibrium Lapse rate](http://wattsupwiththat.com/2012/01/24/refutation-of-stable-thermal-equilibrium-lapse-rates/).

Although both agree that they are incompatible and assert that in very similar ways. Robert G Brown comes to the conclusion that a hydrostatic gas is isothermal in nature, where as Vanquish Opprobrium comes to the conclusion that the second law is likely false.

Vanquish Opprobrium is probably a crackpot, hence the nom de guerre. Yet hydrostatic lapse seems so intuitive. If you place one gas molecule into isolated system by itself, it will be effected by gravity and have less velocity when it is higher up. If more gas molecules enter the system why would the gas molecules stop being slower on average higher up?

Comment: How is the definition of temperature supposed to cool air with the help of gravity?

Comment: @CuriousOne Cooler air is denser and sinks because of gravity? **This has nothing to do with your question**

Comment: @PandaLion98: Whenever I find someone with a giant foam hand with "second law" written on it pointing in the wrong direction I tend to make a joke because that's what it deserves. The second law is an absolute triviality and most people (physicists included) seem to think it's some kind of magic. Your "explanation", by the way, is about 150% off from what's really happening.

Comment: @CuriousOne Yes. That is correct.

Comment: @CuriousOne IDK what your asking. Could you please clarify?

Comment: It means that transport mechanisms in planetary atmospheres are well understood but non-trivial and you need to consult a textbook on the topic if you want to understand radiation balances and thermodynamics of flow phenomena in detail. Most importantly, though, the atmosphere is not an equilibrium phenomenon and one should not try to approach it as one. One one side the planet is exposed to 1.4kW/m^2 in solar radiation, on the other it is radiating into space that is 2.7K cold. Somewhere in this sandwich is your "problem".

Comment: Please Re-read, I have made the question clearer.